# Should MSMQ be installed if we use MSMQ to communicate between applications?

Tags: c#, msmq

Should MSMQ be installed through Add/Remove programs in control panel if we use MSMQ in C#?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in order to use the MSMQ libraries in C# you'll need to have it installed on the machine running the code.

If you're interested in getting it installed with your setup project, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682511/including-msmq-as-a-prerequisite-for-my-application/684513#684513).